# Looping through Unique Data Set to Return Matching Value on a Different Sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I have searched for something similar to what I am asking, and unfortunately there is nothing close to what I am looking for.

I have a unique data set here on Sheet(2):  [image: Data to Loop Through]  The goal is to return the values in the highlighted blue columns if it matches the same "Item#" for the box selected in a dropdown list of the box names on Sheet(1).  Please see Sheet(1) here: [Sheet(1) Set-Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utB1h.jpg).

The Item#'s on Sheet(1) are located in B3:B12 on Sheet(1). - *I've added also another list where I would like my code to run*  In the column next to this is a blank where the matching items in blue would post.

I am trying to use For Loops to accomplish this.  I understand that the data set is weird, but I want to keep it like that for the mere challenge of it (and also because I have a larger data set similar and am just using this as a test run)... My code so far is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
' In order to run code on sheet without a button or enabling in a module
Set KeyCells = Range("A1")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

Dim i, j As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim box As String
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Set rn2 = sh2.UsedRange

box = Sheets(1).Cells.Range("A1")

Dim k1 As Long
k1 = rn2.Rows.Count + rn2.Row - 1

n = 0

For i = 1 To k1
If Sheets(2).Cells(1, i) = box Then
    If n = 0 Then
        Sheets(1).Cells(3, 3).Value = Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2)
        n = n + 1
    End If

    ElseIf n > 0 Then

        For j = 3 To n + 2
            If Sheets(2).Cells(2, i).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2).Value Then

                If Sheets(2).Cells(2, i).Value <> Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2).Value Then
                x = x
                Else
                x = x + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next

    If x = 0 Then
    Sheets(1).Cells(3 + n, 3).Value = Sheets(2).Cells(2, i).Value
    n = n + 1
    End If
End If

x = 0

Next


End If
End Sub
```

Please let me know what you experts think!

Comment: Can you show your other sheets so we can see an example and how it relates to both of your sheets. Make sure to update the values as they should be

Comment: Please clarify; How is Sheet1 B3:B12 set up? B3:B12 is ten cells, but there are 20 cells in the Item list. How many drop-down list do you have and which cells are they located in?

Comment: My goal is to have a Change from the list selection to operate the code and no button.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 2; the macro finds `Sheet1.Range("A1").Value` in `Sheet2` row 1. It then loops through each cell below the found value in `Sheet2`. It then finds each  cells value in `Sheet1`. It will then copy the cells value in `Sheet2` from the next cell to the right, and place the value in the cell in `Sheet1` to the next cell to the right. It then loops down to the next cell in `sheet2`, and performs the same task, etc.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range) 'Works
Dim fndTrgt As Range, fndCel As Range

    If target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Set fndTrgt = Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).Find(target.Value)

        If Not fndTrgt Is Nothing Then
            For i = 1 To 5
                Set fndCel = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D12").Find(fndTrgt.Offset(i).Value)
                If Not fndCel Is Nothing Then
                    fndCel.Offset(, 1).Value = fndTrgt.Offset(i, 1).Value
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I would like it to only match the lookup values in the items in the box selected.

Comment: @mtiger1 Do you need to clear the range in sheet 1 each time a new "Box(n)" is selected in the dropdown list?

Comment: Yes that's the goal.  Also I'm not familiar with offset in the vba but have used it in regular excel formulas.

Comment: Goal is to only match, what I consider "quantities", to the corresponding box in sheet2

Comment: @mtiger1 So, in your example, you Don't want to match on "bb king"? To clarify, do you consider  "bb King" a quantity? Also, your "Sheet1" example is the format you want, right?

Comment: Essentially when I select Box 1 from the drop down, I want Items1-5 to read bb king, 101, 1 set, and so on with the quantity. And I want the same for when I select Box 2, Box 3 etc.  Yes I consider the items in blue on Sheet2 to be quantites - was just using random words to make it more unique.  Yes Sheet1 picture is what I want to use as format.

Comment: @mtiger1 Easy, give me a little time and I will update my answer.

Comment: I think there is some confusion with the way I'm portraying my question.  I understand how to hard code cells to display information.  But I want the quantities to match from the items on Sheet1.  Not just copying and pasting to specific cells.  Because if I were to change the item# on sheet1 bb King will post no matter what.